# Cookies not appearing in Postman Cookie Panel after successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, postman

I am encountering a peculiar issue while testing my login API in Postman. After successfully logging in a user, I can see the cookies in the Cookies tab and notice the 'Set-Cookie' header in the response. However, the cookies are not displayed in the Postman Cookie Panel where all cookies should be listed.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
export const sendToken = (user: IUser, statusCode: number, res: Response) => {

    const accessToken = user.SignAccessToken()
    const refreshToken = user.SignRefreshToken()

    // upload the session to redis 
    redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user) as any)

    // parse enviroment variable 
    const accessTokenExpire = parseInt(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE || '300', 10)
    const refreshTokenExpire = parseInt(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE || '300', 10)

    // options for cookies 
    const accessTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + accessTokenExpire + 1000),
        maxAge: accessTokenExpire + 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: false,
    }

    const refreshTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + refreshTokenExpire + 10),
        maxAge: refreshTokenExpire + 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: false,
    }

    // only set secure true in production
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        accessTokenOptions.secure = true
    }

    res.cookie('access_token', accessToken, accessTokenOptions)
    res.cookie('refresh_token', refreshToken, refreshTokenOptions)


    res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: true,
        user,
        accessToken
    })
}
```

Here's is the postman picture after saving the cookies.

[image]

I expect the cookies to be displayed in the Postman Cookie Panel for further testing and validation.